# Vote_Fu Rails 3 plugin "uninitialized constant Juixe"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I've recently tried to use the Vote_fu plugin to do some simple voting on my rails site.  I was following this guide https://github.com/vshvedov/vote_fu_rails_3

I was able to download the plugin perfectly fine but when I tried to run rails g vote_fu MymodelName or rake db:migrate, they both returned uninitialized constant Juixe (NameError).

Has anyone else had this problem and do you have any solutions to help me fix it?  Thanks for your help!

Edit: The full error is found here http://pastebin.com/3AMGUn44

Comment: Is that the full text of the error?